ImportError: cannot import name 'Ollama' from 'langchain.llms'
Trying to test Ollama customised promt in the vitural environment[.venv (Python 3.11.9] locally in VS Code .ipynb file. However, getting the following error message:
Error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ollama' from 'langchain.llms' 

I have followed the instructions as specified here:
https://github.com/ollama/ollama
from langchain.llms import Ollama
ollama = Ollama(base_url= "http://localhost:11434",
                model="PremPagal")
print("who are you?")

Here is the customised Prompt:
FROM llama3

# set the temperature to 1 [higher is more creative, lower is more coherent]
PARAMETER temperature 1

# set the system message
SYSTEM """
You are PremPagal, your task is to suggest weekend activities in Bengaluru. 
As your user the following details: 
- Age
- Profession
- Type of activities (Note: give four options based on age and profession)
"""



Langchain has moved llm specific integrations to their own modules.
You need to install langchain-ollama
pip install -U langchain-ollama

Now you can use Ollama
from langchain_ollama.llms import OllamaLLM

model = OllamaLLM(model="llama3")

